# Booking Calendar Arrive & Depart Dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This may seem a typical question, but I can't find an answer to this problem.

I have a booking table:

```
book_id  |   arrive_date |   depart_date
1                 2015-07-20     2015-07-22 
2                 2015-07-22     2015-07-23  
3                 2015-07-19     2015-07-20
```

You will see that I have demonstrated that a depart date can be an arrive date  and vice versa

Before a date is added  I check that the date range won't conflict  with dates in the table,  it is important to allow a depart date to be an arrive date as the person will be leaving,  to allow this when I check the dates in the table I ADD a date to the arrive_date  and SUBTRACT a day from the depart_date using this SQL:

```
Select * From booking Where booking.unit_id = 58 
  And ( DATE_ADD(booking.from_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  BETWEEN '2015-07-23' AND '2015-07-24' 
   OR 
  DATE_SUB(booking.to_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   BETWEEN '2015-07-23' AND '2015-07-24' 
      OR '2015-07-23' 
   BETWEEN DATE_ADD(booking.from_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
   AND DATE_SUB(booking.to_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) Limit 1
```

When I added the first date, no problem...same with the second and third, this worked because the first date range I entered a day in between the (20th and 22nd).  Then I try and add '2015-07-23' AND '2015-07-24', which is checked using the above SQL, which is obviously returning a result. I need a way that will allow these dates to be accepted as the 23rd is a depart_date.

Any help would be appreciated

I should also mention that I  also have a table that holds blocked dates "booking_prev", therefore a similar query will also be used to check block dates to those in the booking table before they are entered.

Comment: There's no need to check first. In fact, it's counter-productive because someone may insert a value between you checking and doing whatever comes next.

Comment: yes, although dates will only be displayed and allowed to book if they are not in the booked table, I still need a way of checking a date range is valid first...please see what I have added.

Comment: You do not need to check first. (Unless using transactions) the check can and should happen during the insert.

Comment: if you have a suggestion that would be great......on another part I will I also only want to insert dates in one table if they are not in another.....not sure how this can be done on one insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(book_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,arrive_date DATE NOT NULL
,depart_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2015-07-20','2015-07-22'),
(2,'2015-07-22','2015-07-23'),
(3,'2015-07-19','2015-07-20');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| book_id | arrive_date | depart_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 2015-07-20  | 2015-07-22  |
|       2 | 2015-07-22  | 2015-07-23  |
|       3 | 2015-07-19  | 2015-07-20  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

So, the SELECTs might look like this...

```
SELECT '2015-07-22','2015-07-24' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.arrive_date < '2015-07-24' AND y.depart_date > '2015-07-22'
 WHERE y.book_id IS NULL 
 LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

SELECT '2015-07-23','2015-07-24' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.arrive_date < '2015-07-24' AND y.depart_date > '2015-07-23'
 WHERE y.book_id IS NULL 
 LIMIT 1;
+------------+------------+
| 2015-07-23 | 2015-07-24 |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-07-23 | 2015-07-24 |
+------------+------------+
```

...but you don't need to check them first. I've deliberately written the SELECTs in such a way that the check can happen as part of the INSERT...

```
INSERT INTO my_table (arrive_date,depart_date)
SELECT '2015-07-23','2015-07-24' 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.arrive_date < '2015-07-24' AND y.depart_date > '2015-07-23'
 WHERE y.book_id IS NULL 
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| book_id | arrive_date | depart_date |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 2015-07-20  | 2015-07-22  |
|       2 | 2015-07-22  | 2015-07-23  |
|       3 | 2015-07-19  | 2015-07-20  |
|       4 | 2015-07-23  | 2015-07-24  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

In practice, and depending on the user experience you want to provide, you may want to run the SELECTs first, so that the user can immediately see which dates aren't available, and then run the INSERTs when it comes to making the booking - to make sure that no one grabbed those dates while the user was mid-way through booking.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to show a solution, the insert does the trick.   Just a couple of questions, this is new to me and although it works I can't follow what the (SELECT)x does, and can't seem to find an explanation. As I only want an insert to apply if the dates are not in the insert table and another, would I just add an OR 
  FROM (SELECT 2) x  LEFT  JOIN my_other table z ON z.arrive_date < '2015-07-24' AND z.depart_date > '2015-07-23' WHERE z.book_id IS NULL :  Lastly, my original idea was to check fbefore insert so I could tell the user the error..

Comment: It's a hack really. I just need a dummy table instance for the JOIN to work against. x is an alias for the subquery.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, well although the accepted answer does the job very well, I still needed to check that a date entry was valid, mainly because I was checking dates in the main booking table before I added the to a table that blocked dates.  Anyway, the follow SQL, seems to do all the checks that I need:

```
Select * From booking Where booking.unit_id = 58 And ((booking.arrive_date < '2015-07-23' And booking.depart_date >= '2015-07-24') OR (booking.arrive_date <= '2015-07-23' And booking.depart_date > '2015-07-24') OR (booking.arrive_date >= '2015-07-23' And booking.depart_date <= '2015-07-24') OR ('2015-07-23' > booking.arrive_date And '2015-07-23' < booking.depart_date ) OR ('2015-07-24' > booking.arrive_date And '2015-07-24' < booking.depart_date )) Limit 1
```

A little disappointed at being marked down for the solution I gave as it does check the values in the table, which was one of my requirements, though it is not all that efficient for the actual insert.

Moving on I have expanded on the accepted answer adding more of the fields I am using based on a table to hold prevented booking dates:

INSERT INTO booking_prevent (unit_id,from_date,to_date,note) SELECT 58, '2015-07-28', '2015-07-29', 'My Note' FROM (SELECT 1) x LEFT JOIN booking_prevent y ON y.from_date < '2015-07-29' AND y.to_date > '2015-07-28' And y.unit_id = 58 WHERE y.booking_prevent_id IS NULL LIMIT 1

This works very well, but I am a little stuck how I can do an update on an entry but only make the change...again, if it is valid.  This is what I have, which is a stab in the dark:

UPDATE booking_prevent SET (unit_id,from_date,to_date,note) SELECT 58, '2015-07-20', '2015-07-26', 'Updated Note' FROM (SELECT 1) x LEFT JOIN booking_prevent y ON y.from_date < '2015-07-26' AND y.to_date > '2015-07-20' And y.unit_id = 58 WHERE y.booking_prevent_id IS NULL WHERE booking_prevent_id = 466 LIMIT 1

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: As long as no one submits an insert while you're off checking.

Comment: also time is linear - a fact which my query takes advantage of