# sql : check min and max range values with database min and max range values

Tags: mysql, sql

Guys I have an SQL table with min and max range column. Now i want to check the if my new min and max values are already ranges between the database records or not.

Ex.

```
    ID Title   Min     Max
     1   A    5001    10000
     2   B    15001   20000
```

Now the case is that the new range should not fall within the records as it should be either less than of `5000 range or >10000 and <15000` for example.
Please suggest the query.

Comment: Please be clear with your requirement. What do you want???

Comment: Truly within, and/or just partly?

Comment: So 10001 - 15000 would also be prohibited?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Booking Calendar Arrive & Depart Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346425/booking-calendar-arrive-depart-dates) - although you may need to extend that idea slightly

Comment: I just want to add another range say 'C' as something like 6000 to 9000
So the query should be like it must check that it does not fall within the database range values. So it should not add the given range and gives an error for choose another range

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for the same. ***note** : Upgraded with answer of **simimmo's**(https://stackoverflow.com/users/4965993/simimmo) answer

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE min < v_new_min AND v_new_max < max
OR v_new_min BETWEEN min AND max 
OR v_new_max BETWEEN min AND max
```

Now this query will also check the range within inner values of available range.
Thanx @simimmo and all guys for your generous response.

Answer (score 0):

If the following query returns rows, new range overlaps existing ones.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE v_new_min BETWEEN min AND max
OR v_new_max BETWEEN min AND max
```

Comment: Thanx for the responce...
The above query will be usefull but it will fail with the inner condition.
Ex: for above db i have 5001 - 10000 range. If i gives new range as 6000 - 9000 then the your query returns the no record which means it fails on the condition.
But it got me useful for building my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 0_commission_af_setup where status=0 AND 
stock_id='0102' AND commission_type='discount' AND 
cal_by='0' AND calculation_type='1' AND 
'2' BETWEEN min_range AND max_range OR '3' 
BETWEEN min_range and max_range AND min_range 
BETWEEN '2' AND '3' AND max_range BETWEEN '2'
AND '3' OR min_range>'2' AND max_range<'3'
AND status=0 AND stock_id='0102' 
AND commission_type='discount' AND cal_by='0' 
AND calculation_type='1'
```